# Can you help me solve this summation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

I've added an image of how I've approached this problem.
Any clarity would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: (3) is wrong and the given answer is also wrong.

Comment: Look closely at the index variable in (3). It's not actually a triangle sum!

Comment: You have mistaken $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} n=\overbrace{n+n+\dots+n}^{n-1 \text{ times}}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i=1+2+\dots+(n-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the triangle number sum is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \tfrac12 n (n-1), 
$$
the sum in (3) has the same constant $n$ in each term (the index variable is $i$), hence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} n 
= n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 1 
= n (n-1). 
$$
Thus, the total (original expression) is
$$ 
n (n-1) + n^2 
= 2n^2 - n.
$$

Comment: In your step 2, it is still unclear to me why you have chosen to take n out of the summation. If not a triangle sum, what is it?

Comment: Look closely. The index $i$ runs from $1$ up to $n-1$, but the terms being summed don't depend on $i$, i.e. they are constant. There are $n-1$ terms all the same, so $$n + n + \cdots + n = n (1 + 1 + \cdots + 1) = n (n - 1) $$

Comment: Can you share any resources, strategies, or textbooks that have helped you to better understand summation expansion?

Comment: The main thing is to just write out the terms carefully, treating the expression being summed as a function of the index variable. Sometimes it helps to write out a few terms, i.e. for any $f$ (which may not even explicitly reference $k$), 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^5 f(k) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + f(5).
$$ 
Also, keep in mind that the sum on the right-hand side has many different expressions in the summation notation, i.e. we could shift the index and write 
$$
\sum_{y=2023}^{2027} f(y-2022)
$$

Comment: If you like, think of generating a table of pairs $(\text{index}, \text{value})$ = $(k, f(k))$ like you might with any function, allowing indices in the range $n \leq k \leq N$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c} k & f(k) \\ \hline n & f(n) \\ n+1 & f(n+1) \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ N & f(N) \end{array}
$$
Then, 
$$
\sum_{k=n}^N f(k) 
$$
is just the sum of the values in the table!